# Python twincat ADS changing a bool variable value

Tags: python, ads, plc

For TwinCat PLC ads i am using pyads server,i can get the all the PLC variables values but when i try to change the values by  the function of write by name.this function executes but does not change the variable value.for ref pyads
https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads

```
import pyads
plc = pyads.Connection('5.22.187.194.1.1', pyads.PORT_SPS1)
print("Connecting..")
plc.open()
print("Connected!")
plc.write_by_name('MAIN.Lichtschalter_Hobby1', False, pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)
res=plc.read_by_name('MAIN.Lichtschalter_Hobby1', False, pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)
print(res)
plc.close()
```

Comment: Make sure the value is not overwritten in the PLC. Also read_by_name should not have value inside.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution...
The Actual problem is in the project setting .When you bailed you project.
Step 1: Go to Project settings and check the concurrent variable access.
Everything is good to go

Comment: Really Appreciate Answering your Own Question with a Solution!